# environmental variables not being injected into next.js

Tags: next.js, oauth, environment-variables, google-oauth

```
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
dotenv.config();

export const getGoogleUrl = (from: string) => {
  const clientId: string = process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID!;
  const callback: string = 'http://localhost:3000/api/auth/callback/google';
  console.log(clientId)
  console.log(callback)

  const rootUrl = `https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth`;

  const options = {
    client_id: clientId as string,
    redirect_uri: callback as string,
    access_type: 'offline',
    response_type: 'code',
    prompt: 'consent',
    scope: [
      'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile',
      'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email'
    ].join(' '),
    state: from
  };

  const qs = new URLSearchParams(options);

  return `${rootUrl}?${qs.toString()}`;
};
```

Im using nextJs with app router and I'm trying to set up Oauth However, I came across this issue where the process.env variables were not being registered properly. In the example above, both the CLIENTID and CALLBACK are supposed to be environment variables.

The console.log logs both of the environmental variables correctly, however, it doesn't actually register unless I paste the string directly, like with the callback.

I tried pasting the clientId directly too and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

For NextJS, knowing you are on client/server-side rendering is important when you define your env.

**If you are on client-side.**
Try changing the name of env with prefix "NEXT_PUBLIC_[your env name]".
In your case, it should be `NEXT_PUBLIC_GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID="1234"`.

**Else if you are on server-side.**
The `GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID="1234"` should work.

If you dont know if you are on what side.
For NextJSv13, it is servide-side by default, unless you use has the word 'use client' on the top of your *.tsx, then you are on client-side rendering.
For former versions, it is client-side by default, if you are on servide-side, you would see the `getStaticProps` on your *.tsx file.

See more:
https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/configuring/environment-variables